# Is there a CSS selector in this screenshot?

Tags: css, r

[image]

I've tried using a[href*="genome"] and [title~=Eukaryota] but Rstudio gives me an error message saying Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS).

For more context,

```
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "127.0.0.1",
                             port = 4445L,
                             browserName = "chrome")
element <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "selector")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this test HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="./gen_list.cgi?genome=hs" title="Euk; Opi; Meta">Foo</a>
    <a href="./home" title="Home">Home</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

and using the `rvest` package I can select out that `a` tag using either the match to the `href` or the `title`:

```
> html = read_html("sample.html")
> html_nodes(html,'a[title~="Euk;"]')
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <a href="./gen_list.cgi?genome=hs" title="Euk; Opi; Meta">Foo</a>
> html_nodes(html,'a[href*="genome"]')
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <a href="./gen_list.cgi?genome=hs" title="Euk; Opi; Meta">Foo</a>
```

So I think "this works for me" applies here - maybe RSelenium has a less complete implementation than `rvest`? Tiny examples are often worth testing on, so use mine. Not specifically that the `~=` selector matches on space-separate words in a title, so you need the semicolon at the end of `"Eukaryota;"` - your title string seems to be space separated so that should work.